# Triggering checkbox onchange event in chrome using bookmarklet only

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, checkbox

```
<tr phrase_id="1" class="altRow">   
  <td style="padding:3px; vertical-align:top;"><input type="checkbox" value="1"></td>
  <td class="phraseCode" style="padding:3px; vertical-align:top;">
    EUH 201/201A
  </td>
  <td class="phraseText" style="padding:3px; vertical-align:top;">
     Contains lead. Should not be used on surfaces liable to be chewed or sucked by children. Warning! Contains lead.
  </td>
</tr>
```

The above code is extracted from a web page using F12 in chrome.In the above code there is a `checkbox`which when clicked turns the whole row yellow.So I made a bookmarklet which will check that `checkbox` ,but it is not making the line yellow.here is my bookmarklet

**Javascript**

```
(function(){
  var s = document.getElementsByClassName("phraseCode");
  for (i=0;i<s.length;i++) {
    if(s[i].innerText=="EUH 201/201A") {
      elm=s[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
      elm.checked=true;break;
    }
  }
})();
```

I tried using `elm.onchange()`,but no result.I used `typeof()` to get the type of `onchange` event it returns an `object` not a `function`,why?Again how to trigger  the associated `onchange` event .Please explain me with coding.I am new to javascript.So please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to trigger click event with `elm.onclick()`. Complete bookmarklet code (a little optimized) will become:

```
(function () {
    var s = document.querySelectorAll(".phraseCode");
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        if (s[i].innerText == "EUH 201/201A") {
            var elm = s[i].parentNode.querySelector("input");
            elm.checked = true;
            elm.onclick();
            break;
        }
    }
})();
```

Since `elm.onchange` didn't work for your case, toggling effect is very likely set up with click event on the checkboxes. Also if you are wondering why `typeof elm.onchange` is an object, this is because there are no onchange event bound and then `elm.onchange` is `null`, for which `typeof` returns `object`.

If the event is bound using `addEventListener` you may need to create an event and dispatch it manually like in this example http://jsfiddle.net/mx1o3579/.

Comment: So events are bound with addEventListener then. Try the demo I posted with the code triggering events in this case.

Comment: Thanks a lot .You got the concept.Ok then how to implement the same effect using bookmarklet.I mean i want to create a bookmarklet which will do the same thing pragmatically.

Comment: Just wrap it into bookmarklet like you did with your own code.

Comment: Thanks a lot .it worked like a charm.Thank you so much.I am very happy.How could I contact you if I would have further doubts? could you please help me to connect with you?

Comment: Just leave the comment here with the link to your further questions if you have any.

Comment: No, not for this question.if I have doubts for other questions then how I can connect you?Ok I will connect with you using linkedIn profile.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table border="1">
 <tr  class="altRow">   
     <td style="padding:3px; vertical-align:top;">
     <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="chbox"></td>

     <td class="phraseCode" style="padding:3px; vertical-align:top;">EUH 201/201A</td>

      <td class="phraseText" style="padding:3px; vertical-align:top;">Contains lead. Should not be used on surfaces liable to be chewed or sucked by children. Warning! Contains lead.</td>
 </tr>
 </table>

<style>
.selected
{

background-color:yellow;
}
</style>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".altRow").click(function()
{
    alert('ddd');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
<style>
.selected
{
    background-color:yellow;
}
</style>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>

<script>
$(".chbox").click(function()
{
    $(".altRow").toggleClass('selected');
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the current code, the control is not entering into the for loop.
If you print the length of the variable 's', it is 0.
I suggest you to use 'getElementById'.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use jquery then take a look at .trigger() docs are [here](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/). With jquery you can trigger an event like this

```
$('.some_class').trigger('click');
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this working fiddle with plain javascript
http://jsfiddle.net/mrk_m/jvhogyna/3/
It registers event handler on element.
    `// create inbuilt event 
    var event = new MouseEvent('click', {
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true
    })

    // In loop register handler to change color. and then simulate event
    for ( i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
        console.log(s[i]);
        if (s[i].innerHTML == "EUH 201/201A") {
            elm = s[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
            elm.onchange = changeBgColor;
            // dispatch click event
            elm.dispatchEvent(event);
            break;
        }
    }

    // Handler that changes color of entire row
    function changeBgColor (e) {
        if (!e.target.checked) {
            rowEle.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        } else {
            rowEle.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
        }
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
    }`

You can set background color for altRow from js or from css. If you want to use css, still you need to alter some class for  from js in event handler.  Also, You have to wrap  inside  in order to execute for loop.